# Error: Unable to create the Web site 'https://xya.domain.com'. Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, https, iis-6

Try to publish a web forms asp.net application on iis6 running on win2k server.  The site requires https protocol. I am running visual studio 2010.  I am successfully able to publish on test server but always on production since last few updates it throws this error.

**Error: Unable to create the Web site 'https://xyz.domain.xyz'.  Forbidden**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.  It turned out that there was a proxy server interfering with  iis ssl settings and I didn't looked at web server extensions for .NET framework v4.